# English lit journals publishing graduate-level works

Tags: publications, online-publication

As an MA student interested in pursuing the academic career, I am well aware that it's advisable to have papers published as soon as possible in order to boost one's CV and eventually gain admission to a PhD programme.

Therefore, here's my question: are there any academic journals which routinely publish graduate-level papers about English literature, or at least are willing to accept and assess such submissions? I am thinking of something like those lower-tier journals, often funded by departments, which are able to publish relevant contributions from non-previously established researchers.

Thanks for your contribution.

Comment: I'm wondering if it is true in English literature that applicants for the Ph.D. program typically already have publications?  Or is that only in other fields like Computer Science and physics?  My (uninformed) guess is that such programs may ask you to submit samples of your writing, but would not expect it to have been published.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, your status as student, senior lecturer or professor should not matter in terms of publish in a journal. If your idea is original and your research is relevant and situated in the current debates of the scientific community, then try to publish your texts. Talk to your professors or supervisors about it and tell them about your plan. Maybe, they have suggestions and can give you feedback on the text that you have in mind for submission. 
 Nevertheless, keep in mind, that your term paper or master thesis is not a journal article. I guess, you have to do a lot to rewriting and re-structuring your text that it will eventually become a published article. Moreover, publishing a text takes a lot of time (from submitting to the final version to get an onlinefirst publication, it can take 1-2 years). I don't know in which year of your master program you are, but eventually, the publication might happen after you are already accepted as a PhD candidate ;)

There are probably student-run journals who especially address young scholars to submit their papers. For this, just google... 

 Literally, I just searched for it and found 2 websites which might be relevant for you: https://complit.fas.harvard.edu/journalsconferences-graduate-students and http://www.highpoint.edu/urcw/student-journal-publishing-opportunities-politics-international-affairs-law-2/

Comment: Thank you for your advice :)  I've already spoken with my advisor about that, but I wanted also to hear suggestions from someone else. I also saw the Harvard website, but I thought the journals mentioned were perhaps too high-tier for my first submission. Thanks also for reminding me of the long time required to publish: indeed, it is likely I'll be already in the PhD before seeing my work in some journal - though submission/publication times may vary, I guess

Comment: Indeed, it varies, but if the lower-ranked journals have a peer review process (and you should definitely consider only peer review journals), then it will at least take 6 months (based on my experiences as reviewer and author in such grad journals). There are also probably grad conferences that might be interesting for you as well to present your research (it's not a publication, but as young researcher, getting some conference experience is nice too)